# Triggering an Ext.net button click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, ext.net

I have an ext:button. I want to trigger it's OnClick event by JavaScript based on the condition of a confirm message.

My Button

```
<ext:Button ID="btnAddEsya" Text="text" runat="server" Icon="Add" >
    <DirectEvents>
        <Click OnEvent="btnAddEsya_Click" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        </Click>
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

Code Behind (only relevant parts)

```
[DirectMethod]
    public void btnAddEsya_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (/*Checking conditions here*/)
        {
            X.Msg.Confirm("Warning", "Save?", new JFunction { Fn = "SaveLine" }).Show();
        }

}
```

Java Script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var SaveLine = function (btn) {
            if (btn == 'yes') {
                alert('TEST YES');
                NewLine.click();
                document.getElementById('btnAddEsya').click();


            }
            else if (btn == 'no')
            { alert('TEST NO'); }
        };
            </script>
```

So far I tried this method, the __doPostBack('btnAddEsya','OnClick'); method and assigning the buttons to variables and calling them as variablename.click(). None of them worked.

Can it be about ext.net buttons Click OnEvent ?

Edit:

Recently I tried this too, and it didn't work either. Also

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        btnAddEsya = document.getElementById('<%= btnAddEsya.ClientID %>');
        var SaveLine = function (btn) {
            if (btn == 'yes') {
                alert('TEST YES');
                btnAddEsya.click();
                }
            else if (btn == 'no')
            { alert('TEST NO'); }
        };
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?

```
#{btnAddEsya}.fireEvent("click");
```

Comment: I came across it on my own too but I'm not sure where to use it. Is it inside javascript function or on somewhere else?

Comment: You use it where you want to fire the click event, in this case after the confirm message.

Comment: It gives an error when I add it under the confirm message inside the if. The error is " Preprocessor directive expected"

Comment: You get that error after replacing "btnAddEsya.click();" with "#{btnAddEsya}.fireEvent("click");" in your javascript code?

Comment: No, my confirm message is inside C# button click function. Since you said after confirm message...:D

Comment: I meant after the user confirms in javascript xD in your SaveLine javascript function that it is call after the confirm message. If you put #{btnAddEsya}.fireEvent("click"); in that javascript function, it should work.

Comment: I did that but now confirm message is not appearing. I was so hopeful about this one :(

Comment: Could you please rollback your code till the point when you have a confirm message appearing and your javascript function SaveLine alerting yes or no? Once you have that, if you put #{btnAddEsya}.fireEvent("click"); after the aleter, or event btnAddEsya.fireEvent("click"); should work, if not, could you provide any error message?

Comment: I might be approaching this all wrong. My button had directevents. Should have listeners and a handler inside to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, I'm sorry, I thought that you wanted to call a javascript click event, my mistake.

Try this code in your button:

```
<DirectEvents>
    <Click OnEvent="btnAddEsya_Click" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <Confirmation ConfirmRequest="true" Title="Warning" Message="Save?" />
    </Click>
</DirectEvents>
```

It will ask for confirmation before calling your DirectEvent.